# Reactjs error on return component

Tags: javascript, npm, syntax-error, reactjs

I'm following a React JS tutorial however I find myself with the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>      Error in ./src/Components/Projects.js Syntax error: Unexpected token (15:10)
>
> ```
> return {
>     <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} />`    
>     ^     
> };
> ```

But I am following the tutorial exactly as it is written, but the teacher does not have the same error as me.

This is my **App.js** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
        projects: []
    }
}
componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({
        projects: [

            {
                title: 'Business Website',
                category: 'Web Design'
            },

            {
                title: 'Social App',
                category: 'Mobile Development'
            },

            {
                title: 'Ecomerce Shopping Cart',
                category: 'Web Development'
            }

       ]
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            My App
            <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My **Project.js** file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem';

class Projects extends Component {

  render() {

    let projectItems;
    if(this.props.projects) {

      projectItems = this.props.projects.map(project => {

        return {

          <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} />

        };

      });

    }

    return (

      <div className="Projects">
        {projectItems}
      </div>

    );

  }

}

export default Projects;
```

And my **ProjectItem.js** file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ProjectItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="Project">
        <strong>{this.props.prject.title}</strong>: {this.props.project.category}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectItem;
```

I'm using **create-react-app**

Comment: Try removing the `{}` around your `ProjectItem` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parens, not braces:

```
return (
    <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} />
);
```